# Replacement motherboard in fried laptop

Tags: laptop, processor, motherboard

So basically I have a laptop with a fried motherboard. Everything else works: HDD, RAM, CPU, screen etc. Replacing the motherboard is too expensive because it's half the price of the laptop and I'm poor. I need a computer badly. Can I somehow buy a different, cheaper laptop motherboard to connect to the monitor, mouse, keyboard and add RAM, HDD, CPU? What should I look for in a laptop motherboard so it would be compatible with the CPU? Is socket type enough? I do not care about the exterior or that it wouldn't fit in the case or anything else.

Comment: You'll need more information than just the CPU socket type. Could you list out the product names of all the other parts that still work?

Comment: Its worth looking at what works. Chances are your HDD could be transferred over. Your screen might fit into another motherboard, or trivially, and fairly cheaply have a driver board added to it. As for "something that's a computer that's cheap" - what sort of budget are we talking about? What sort of ram do you have? is the HDD sata or pata? what socket's the CPU?

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. I want to use all other still working parts which include sodimm 4gb ram, sata hdd 500gb, i5 2,4ghz 430m socket pga988 I believe, Dell n5010 screen. I could add all those parts to other cheaper not dell motherboard and it should be compatible I think I just need to find the right board. BTW I would use external monitor and budget is 50 eur